# swift userNotification clicking

Tags: swift, select, click, usernotifications

How can I handle when notification is clicked?

adding action means adding new button to notification, I don't want to add a button; I want to go to special view controller when notification is selected like `builder.setContentIntent` in android.

I read 
[Managing Your App’s Notification Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1)
but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **ios 10 or later** there is two new method which handles notification.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

> This Method called when user tap on notification when app is in foreground.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

> This Method called when app is in background.

And for **< ios 10**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

> This Method called when app is in background.(You won't able to see notification if app is in foreground but you can get notification in above method)

And For Notification Permission

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }

    if !UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications {

        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }else if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
 return true
 }
```